# My view port option is missing from material panel

Tags: customization, panel

[image]

The above is what I saw in a tutorial video and below are my panel options.

[image]

The reason I am asking this is in the video he was viewing textures in 3D viewport object mode but when I do it I don't see textures applied in the viewport at all.

Edited: I have blender version 2.79b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2.79 you have these options in the Settings.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I assumed the lecture is using the current blender version because the video just came out 2 days ago but I was wrong.